# Bitcoin and other non-ethereum coins on EtherDelta Exchnage?

Tags: bitcoin, etherdelta

Is there a Bitcoin equivalent coin on EtherDelta for trade? Say if I wanted to trade my ether for btc/ltc/doge on the exchange. How would that be possible?

Answer (score 1):

Nope, the cross chain stuff still isn't there.  You can look at projects like Polkadot or Cosmos who are trying to solve it, but nothing that you can practically use yet.  Right now semi-decentralized options like shapeshift are really the best bet.

Comment: I've sometimes seen non-ethereum coins on EtherDelta but they are obviously fake. Unfortunately I'm sure some people fall for it.